# CSS: layout with 3 columns and main content with floating elements

Tags: css, layout, css-float

I wish this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/klodenet/b3NS7/2/) can explain what I want.
When I have a layout with 3 columns (one left, one right and the last on center (without flot set on CSS), the layout is perfect! But, if I want to add some elements in the center space with float set in CSS, if I set a "clear:left;", I get the new elements at the end of the content of left column... It's annoying result!

However, if you see my fiddle, you can understend more better what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understant you correctly you cant add element on center with `clear:left;`, no reason to do that. Give all element to `display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;` then set up your html like that. They will be one left, one right and the last on center, and a unwanted element.

```
<div class="width:200px;/* you can set if you want */">fist elem</div>
<div>content</div>
<div>some elements</div>
<div class="width:200px;/* you can set if you want */">last elem</div>
```

Comment: the vertical-align! you're right! wonderful! It's very useful! thanks again for you precious help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you carefully use the width,min-width,max-width css attributes,
and be very careful with position:relative and display:block.

Use margins at the very end having worked with the above css attributes, and do not work in css without **BORDERS** I keep writing this for all beginners in css, but never forget that rule in css because it is hard for you as well as others to see where design starts breaking if you do not add borders to elements.

And another point to remember when using floats, make sure that floated elements have equal heights because

```
|  |
|  |    | |
```

when each of these divs (left one with height 100px and right one with 50px) is floated right leads to the right div coming below left div.

Comment: thanks Nina, but I'm not a "really" beginner... I'm studying CSS since 2001, but the vertical-align is an unknown and "i-never-supposed-it-could-work"... But this mind born with the tedious IE!!!

Comment: Oh! my bad then :( thanks for upvote sir; besides I have bookmarked this page, because there is something new to learn here.